# Cordova Firebase Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, cordova, firebase

I'm having trouble getting the Facebook login to work on my app using Cordova.

I added the Cordova In App Browser plugin to my config.xml like so:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
```

And I am successfully prompted with the facebook dialog window to enter my email and password but once I log in, nothing is displayed. It's weird because it was working before and I'm not sure where the problem is now even after going back and undoing changes to the code.

Using "alerts" I was able to pinpoint that the code past the `ref.authWithOAuthRedirect` is not run anymore, so I'm not sure what the problem is exactly.

Here is my `login.html` file:

```
<body>
<button>
Login To Facebook
</button>
<div id="info"></div>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script>
    $('button').click(function(){

    var ref = new Firebase("https://xxx.firebaseio.com");

    ref.authWithOAuthPopup("facebook", function(error, authData) {
      if (error) {
        if (error.code === "TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE") {
          // fall-back to browser redirects, and pick up the session
          // automatically when we come back to the origin page
          ref.authWithOAuthRedirect("facebook", function(error) { 
            $('#info').append(authData.facebook.displayName 
            + " " + authData.facebook.email + '<br />');
            $('#info').append('<img src="' + authData.facebook.profileImageURL + '"/>');
          });
        }
      } else if (authData) {
        // user authenticated with Firebase
        $('#info').append(authData.facebook.displayName 
        + " " + authData.facebook.email + '<br />');
        $('#info').append('<img src="' + authData.facebook.profileImageURL + '"/>');
      }
    }, {
      scope: "email" // the permissions requested
    });

    });
</script>
</body>
```

And here is my `config.xml`:

```
<widget id="com.xxx.xxx" version="1.9.0">
    <name>My App</name>
    <description>
        Your app description here. 
    </description>
        <author email="example@gmail.com" href="http://example.com">
            My App
        </author>
    <content src="login.html"/>
    <access origin="*" />
    <access origin="https://xxx.firebaseio.com" />
    <access origin="https://auth.firebase.com" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Facebook app configuration, click on the Settings tab on the left-hand navigation menu. Then go to the Advanced tab at the top and scroll down to the Security section. At the bottom of that section, add https://auth.firebase.com/v2//auth/facebook/callback to your Valid OAuth redirect URIs and click Save Changes at the bottom of the page.

[Reference](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/facebook.html)

**EDIT**
I would recommend you use the following two libraries for facebook login on device -
If the user has facebook installed on device use [cordova-facebbok4](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4)
This will automatically prompt the native facebook application to login.

If the facebook is not installed you can write a catch method that uses [OpenFB](https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB#creating-a-facebook-application)

In any case you must use authWithOAuthToken for facebook login.
Here is an example of obtaining token with cordova plugin

```
//Inside Ionic ready
if($ionicPlatform.isWebView()){
$cordovaFacebook.login(["public_profile", "email"]).then(function(success){
                var token = success.authResponse.accessToken; 

                ref.authWithOAuthToken("facebook", token, function(error, authUserData){
                    if(error){
                        console.error("Authentication failed:", error);
                        $ionicPopup.alert({
                            title: "Error",
                            template: 'There was an error logging you in with facebook.'
                        });
                        d.reject(error);
                    }
                    else{ //Logged in!}
else{
//code for open fb login.}
```

Comment: I've tried all of the following, and none of them have solved the problem: `https://auth.firebase.com/v2/myFirebase/auth/facebook/callback`
`https://auth.firebase.com/v2/auth/facebook/callback`
`http://example.com`
`http://example.com/login.html` `http://example.com/main.html` 
`http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html`

Comment: Do you get an error on your console after facebook login?

Comment: If you are trying to use facebook login on your device you will have to use
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/authwithoauthtoken.html

Comment: thanks so much for you answer, is there anyway that I can use the 'authWithOauthToken' feature with my current code, without having to resort to other plugins?

Comment: Quick update, I was successfully able to alert the user's access token through `authData.facebook.accessToken` with the authWithOAuthPopup function. Would it work if I passed the access token through as the paramater of the authWithOauthToken function?